# Error while running Sinatra app on Cloud 9

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cloud9-ide

I am using cloud 9 IDE to follow this [tutorial](http://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/sinatra-basics?ref=lnav). How can I run Sinatra on Cloud 9 ? I created a blank workspace in cloud 9, ran `gem install` from command line. But running Sinatra from command line doesn't work. I notice it flags `Important: use ENV[PORT] as the port and ENV[IP] as the host in your scripts!` after starting the server. How can I make this work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the c9 window says "*...; make sure it's on port $PORT with $IP as the IP address*", this is, don't replace `$PORT` or `$IP` with your own values, they're values already defined, you can check it using `echo $IP && echo $PORT`.

Try running `ruby hi.rb -p $PORT -o $IP` within your Sinatra project directory.

You can also define the port and ip as environment variables as the flags you noticed say running the `export PORT=<port> && export IP=<ip>` command, and then access to them within any ruby file as `ENV['PORT']` or `ENV['IP']`.

**Note**: For some reason when I use the route `get '/hi'` it didn't work running on c9.io, but it did it correctly in my local machine, if you have the same mistake try just `get '/'`.